# Getting rsync failures randomly

Tags: files, rsync, capistrano

I am getting the following `rsync` errors randomly from my capistrano scripts.

```
rsync: stat "/app/test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.SB4uq7" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: rename "/app/test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.SB4uq7" -> "target/test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar": No such file or directory (2)
rsync: mkstemp "/app/.run-test-reports.sh.dY7r8H" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

I am using the following `rsync` command:

`rsync -Oarvzp --progress "#{source}" "#{user}@#{destination_host}:#{destination}/"`

Can someone help me in solving it ?

Answer (score 2):

depquid is very likely correct.

I suggest you add this:

`--exclude='test.*.jar.?????' --exclude='.run-text.*.sh.?????'`

to the rsync command, maybe more; `--exclude=app` may also work as an alternative, depending on what you are doing.

Btw, I think your implied -r and -p are redundant with -a.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a hunch, but are you running tests at the same time that you are deploying? The filenames look like temporary files that are being created and deleted while rsync is running.

Comment: No i first copy the artifacts, and then i run the tests. I am often getting these errors in different pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you ran multiple rsync in parallel.  If so, then I think what might be happening is that a concurrent rsync (or some other process) deletes temporary files of your rsync.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/207961)

Comment: Collect 50 ups, then you will be able to comment. It is not so hard as it seems, I've just got 65 with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389462/52236) simple answer.

Comment: @Thomas, huh? The second sentence is very much intended to "help [the person] in solving it". Well, technically to answer the question you just need to say "yes", but I imagine that's not what you had in mind.